# Constraint of an unknown type passed to function

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, minimize

Hi I am doing a minimization problem and I wanted to try the `'trust-constr'` method, with scipy function `optimize.minimize`, to compare it with the 'SLSQP' results. Unfortunatly I don't know why when I set my method to `'trust-constr'`, it tells me that :

ValueError: `constraint` of an unknown type is passed.

The code is the following:

```
con1 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': eq2}
con2 =  {'type':'ineq', 'fun' : ieq_bck2}
con3 =  {'type':'ineq', 'fun' : ineq_rb2}
con4 =  {'type':'ineq', 'fun' : ls2}

con = ([con1, con2, con3, con4])

scipy.optimize.minimize(fitness2, opt, method = 'trust-constr', jac = 
'cs', hess = h1, constraints = con)
```

Any idea of how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), your variable `con` must be a dictionary. There is also an example, con must be something like:

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 2},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 6},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[0] + 2 * x[1] + 2})
```

So in your case, do this:

```
con = (con1, con2, con3, con4)
```

Comment: still doesn't work even if i do it this way, same message error comes out

Comment: ok, then, can you udpate your question with a minimal code example that I can reproduce ?

Comment: I found the problem, for the case of 'trust-constr' you have to create the constraints trough the function LinearConstraint of the same module, for the other options this problem isn't encountered